# C# selecting an image and drawing it in a panel

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple list of filenames of (supported) images in a listbox. When I select a filename I want to have the image drawn in a panel (like a preview).

How do I access the panel to actually load the image?

Comment: Please add some code that'll help us answering the question.

Comment: Is this a Windows Form application?

Comment: JMK yes.

@the_ajp it is pretty much a blank project with a listbox and a panel. There isn't really any code other than what VS generated and a single loop that adds some strings to the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the SelectedIndexChanged event handler of your listbox. You can find this by clicking on your listbox, looking in the properties pane, clicking on the lightning bolt and double clicking the blank space beside `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentImageLocation = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Image myImage = Image.FromFile(currentImageLocation);
    panel1.BackgroundImage = myImage;
}
```

You obviously need to update the generic names above to the ID's of your listbox and panel

Answer (score 0):

Simply get file's location on listbox's item selection and set panel's background image property to that location.

Comment: Oh, so `background image` is what is usually used for loading images?